# Sorting part of a Scala Array

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

In Java I can write

```
private final List<Point> points = ...;
...
Collections.sort(points.subList(start, end), sorter);
```

(This is used as part of an algorithm that sorts the entire `List` in a particular way.)

I'd like to be able to express the equivalent in Scala with `Array`. I have tried this:

```
val a = Array("z", "y", "x", "w", "v")
val b = a.slice(1, 4)
Sorting.quickSort(b)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work as the `slice` copies `a`. How can I sort part of an array in Scala?

Edit: the intention is that `sorter` becomes a Scala `Ordering`.

Answer (score 4):

As an `Array[T]` in Scala is [with one to one correspondents to a Java array](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays.html), you can use the same in place `java.util.Arrays.sort`:

```
scala> val arr = Array(1, 5, 2, 3, 7, 9)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 5, 2, 3, 7, 9)

scala> java.util.Arrays.sort(arr, 0, 3)

scala> arr
res22: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 5, 3, 7, 9)
```

Comment: I should have said: I wanted to use a Scala `Ordering` with it... (see `sorter` above). Does that work?

Comment: So you want to use `Ordering` on a collection, but modify it partially and in place?

Comment: Yes please, if possible. If not I will just fall back to using Java Comparator with a Java ArrayList.

Comment: @Mohan do you have any particular reasons for wanting to use `Ordering` for this ?

Comment: A general (and perhaps in this case misguided?) desire not to mix Java and Scala constructs willy-nilly.